# XML Deserializing returns "some" null values

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Here's my XML:

```
<Events>
  <Event>
    <content_id>6442452774</content_id>
    <content_title>Title of the event</content_title>
    <content_html>
<Date>2015-11-18</Date>
<EventType>Events</EventType>
<Description>
<p>this is an "event"</p>
</Description>
<Speakers>speaker1 LLC<br />speaker2<br />Jspeaker3</Speakers>
<Time>5:30 - 6:00pm Registration<br />6:00 - 7:00pm Panel Discussion<br />7:00 - 8:00pm Networking Reception</Time>
<Where></Where>
<RegistrationInfo>Please contact <a href="mailto:events@events.com">events@events.com</a> to register for this event.</RegistrationInfo>
<Registration>false</Registration>
</content_html>
    <date_created>2015-10-24T14:24:12.333</date_created>
    <folder_id>262</folder_id>
    <content_teaser>this is the content "can you display it."</content_teaser>
    <content_text>text of the vent "more text" a lot of text here </content_text>
    <end_date>2015-11-19T21:35:00</end_date>
    <content_type>1</content_type>
    <template_id>43</template_id>
    <content_status>A</content_status>
  </Event>
<Event>.... Other events   </Event>
<Events>
```

and here's are my classes:

```
 public class Serializable_Events
    {
        [XmlElement("Event")]
        public List<Serializable_Event> EventList = new List<Serializable_Event>();
    }
    public class Serializable_Event
    {
        [XmlElement("content_id")]
        public string content_id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("content_title")]
        public string content_title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("content_html")]
        public Serializable_Event_ContentHTML ContentHTML { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string content_teaser { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("content_text")]
        public string content_text { get; set; }
    }
    public class Serializable_Event_ContentHTML
    {
        [XmlElement("Date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("EventType")]
        public string EventType { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Speakers")]
        public string Speakers { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Time")]
        public string Time { get; set; }


        [XmlElement("Where")]
        public string Where { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("RegistrationInfo")]
        public string RegistrationInfo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Registration")]
        public bool Registration { get; set; }

        //ignored html tags
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string p { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string br { get; set; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public string a { get; set; }

    }
```

Implementation:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Serializable_Events));
            var data = (Serializable_Events)ser.Deserialize(new StreamReader(@"events.xml"));
```

My problem is that some attributes are null and some are not (see the screenshot)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ones that are null, like `<Description>` are due to malformed
`XML`.

You are storing `HMTL` directly in `XML` with text all over the place, and the serializer is not expecting that; further you are telling the serializer to ignore HTML tags using `XmlIgnore` which is intended for XML tags with properly formed XML. That's a wrong use of `XmlIgnore`

> All XML which contains non-XML mark-up should be wrapped in [CDATA sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076(v=vs.110).aspx); this will solve your problem. Further, you can remove all of the `XmlIgnore` code as well since it's not needed.

Your XML should look like this:

```
<Events>
    <Event>
        <content_id>6442452774</content_id>
        <content_title>Title of the event</content_title>
        <content_html>
            <Date>2015-11-18</Date>
            <EventType>Events</EventType>
            <Description>
                <![CDATA[<p>this is an ""event""</p>]]>
            </Description>
            <Speakers>
                <![CDATA[speaker1 LLC<br />speaker2<br />Jspeaker3]]>
            </Speakers>
            <Time>
                <![CDATA[5:30 - 6:00pm Registration<br />6:00 - 7:00pm Panel Discussion<br />7:00 - 8:00pm Networking Reception]]>
            </Time>
            <Where></Where>
            <RegistrationInfo>
                <![CDATA[Please contact <a href='mailto:events@events.com'>events@events.com</a> to register for this event.]]>
            </RegistrationInfo>
            <Registration>false</Registration>
        </content_html>
        <date_created>2015-10-24T14:24:12.333</date_created>
        <folder_id>262</folder_id>
        <content_teaser>this is the content 'can you display it.'</content_teaser>
        <content_text>text of the vent 'more text' a lot of text here </content_text>
        <end_date>2015-11-19T21:35:00</end_date>
        <content_type>1</content_type>
        <template_id>43</template_id>
        <content_status>A</content_status>
    </Event>
</Events>"
```

Comment: @Dimitriy Thakns for the response. I was expenting that and that's why i used the [XmlIgnore] for the html tags and it doesn't seem to fix the issue.
My problem is that i inherited a bunch of xml files that i need to manage and it will be hard for me to add the CDATA for all of the html tags. but if that's the only way , then i will go ahead and do it. Please advise!

Comment: Is there a way to get the whole block after <Description> and not parse it?

Comment: See my updated answer. If you are getting malformed XML like this, and you need to normalize it, I would look at an HTML parser (like HtmlAgilityPack) to read the bad XML and rebuild it into good XML, and then run your serializer code on it. Clearly, that's a different problem / question though...

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker yes but not with an XML serializer; this is where I would use an HTML parser and clean this stuff up. XML is much more structured than HTML and when there are random nodes like <p>, <br /> everywhere in between text, the XML serializer doesn't know what to do with that (rightfully so).

Comment: Yeah it clearly is not working for the OP. XmlIgnore is meant to ignore XML elements and not parse them, not to fix bad XML and magically make it into good XML by ignoring HTML markup and then assuming the rest of it is good -- think about it -- how would it know which elements to keep and what the structure looks like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94819/discussion-between-alundra-the-dreamwalker-and-dmitriy-david-khaykin).